# PostGIS change geometry type of column from LineString to MultiLineString

Tags: postgis, geometry, linestring

I have tried the following, however the query just hangs and doesn't complete:

```
ALTER TABLE public.line_layer ALTER COLUMN geom type geometry(MultiLineString, 27700);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the SRID and it worked:

```
ALTER TABLE public.line_layer ALTER COLUMN geom type geometry(MultiLineString);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have existing data in the column then you may need to reproject it which can be done as:

```
ALTER TABLE public.line_layer 
ALTER COLUMN geom type geometry(MultiLineString, 27700)
USING ST_TRANSFORM(geom, 27700);
```

Or if you had simply not set a SRID on the column before but the data was in OSGB (27700) you could simply set the SRID:

```
ALTER TABLE public.line_layer 
ALTER COLUMN geom type geometry(MultiLineString, 27700)
USING ST_SETSRID(geom, 27700);
```

Comment: I am afraid this does not work (for going from LineString to MultiLineString). One needs to use st_multi in the USING clause. Ex:
`ALTER TABLE public.line_layer 
ALTER COLUMN geom type geometry(MultiLineString, 27700)
USING ST_TRANSFORM(ST_MULTI(geom), 27700);`