# PostGIS: Convert geometry type from MultiLineString back to LineString

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, geometry, geometry-conversion

I am working with a PostGIS database where I want to alter the geometry type from MultiLineString to LineString. My table used to be a LineString, so I know that all lines are simple, single line features that should be able to be represented as LineString. But as QGIS stores everything in a temporary layer as MultiLineString after any processing, I now have a MultiLineString that is not supported by the plugin I want to use.

I found [this question asking for the other direction](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/403607/postgis-change-geometry-type-of-column-from-linestring-to-multilinestring). So I know about ST_Multi and using ALTER COLUMN in general.

**Is there a way to go back to a simple LineString geometry type?** Either within PostGIS or in any other way withiin QGIS without loosing attributes (i.e. creating a new LineString table in PostGIS; which would be way to tedious as my table is quite big)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are **sure** every record is indeed a simple line string, you can use [`st_geometryN(geom,1)`](https://postgis.net/docs/en/ST_GeometryN.html) to get the 1st (and only) simple geometry.

```sql
alter table testml 
  alter column geom type geometry(linestring,4326) using st_geometryN(geom,1);
```

Comment: worked like a charm, thank you!

Comment: I take that back. Execution worked, all attributes are still intact, there are features in my table, but all geometries itself are not visible any more. So maybe the geometries weren't all simple geometries after all?

I had a LineString layer that I have clipped with a polygon. I assumed, all features would still be simple lines...

Comment: This kind of assumption should have been validated **before**. If you had multiple segments per line, well, so long for all but the 1st one. In such case, the solution would have been to create a new table and to select/insert attributes + each individual parts using st_dump

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  The alter table statement deleted all the geometry because `st_geometryn` is 1 based, not 0.  So you set all the geometry to null with that update statement.

Comment: @jbalk well spotted, thanks, I have updated the answer! Hum, I wonder why st_geometryN doesn't throw an error when called with 0 (or negative) parameter

Comment: Yeah, an error would be useful there.  I wonder if there's already an issue/request for that

Comment: You had me panicking for a second.  I use that function a lot :-)

Comment: for those interested, here is the [request](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/5478) so it throws an error

Comment: sorry for the late reply. All that being said, it of course workes with (geom,1), keeping all lines intact.